# How can I make checkbox with different shape (like triangle) and be clickable only on the triangle area?

Tags: html, css

How can I make checkbox with different shape (like triangle) and be clickable only on the triangle area?

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

    input[type=checkbox] + label {
        display: inline-block;
        background: url("http://www.bildites.lv/images/8pzgmznr/54227/original.jpg") no-repeat;
        height: auto;
        margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
        padding: 25px 0 0 80px;
    }
    input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
        height: auto;
        margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
        padding: 25px 0 0 80px;
        background: url("http://www.bildites.lv/images/hfy3gneu/54217/original.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<div>
        <input type="checkbox" checked id="c1" />
        <label for="c1"></label>
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You have the checkbox working just fine. All you need is to give it a proper width and height. See this -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ryc60dc7/

Answer (score 2):

To create a triangle make use of `border` property

```css
input {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: block;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label {
  border-top: 20px solid red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  border-bottom: 20px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='demo'>
<label for="demo"></label>
```

Comment: As far as he don´t need a complex trianlge i like this solution

Answer (score 1):

Make the label smaller. (clicking on an label just is like clicking on the input itself)

I used:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
```

on both input stylings.
Use a surrounding div to give the triangle a position.

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML

```
<map>
```

and

```
<area>
```

to define the shape on your image, which in your case could be a triangle on a transparent .png or .gif image. You could have a

```
<input type="hidden">
```

in your form and change it's value with javascript. With javascript, you could also change the image after it has been clicked inside your shape. This is how jQuery can detect where you click. In the example below it names what was clicked. Use the same jQuery to change the value of a hidden text input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("area").click(function(){
            var x = $(this).attr("id");
            $("#result").text(x);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets.</p>

    <img src="http://cakewalkwebsites.com/img/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

    <map name="planetmap">
        <area id="sun" shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="#sun">
        <area id="mercury" shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="#mercury">
        <area id="venus" shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="#venus">
    </map>

    <p id="result"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't put the image inside an INPUT, just put it inside a DIV. When clicking inside the triangle (or any other shape) on your image inside that div, have javascript change the value of a hidden input. Let me know if you understand.

Comment: Max Naumov, I added more detail so you can see how clicking a shape on an image can change the value of an input field. Just copy the whole html document, paste it in your editor and try it.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a `clip-path`.

[**Clip-path @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

> The clip-path CSS property **prevents a portion of an element from getting displayed** by defining a clipping region to be displayed i.e, only a specific region of the element is displayed. The clipping region is a path specified as a URL referencing an inline or external SVG, or shape method such as circle(). The clip-path property replaces the now deprecated clip property.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]+label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 1em;
  background: red;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  background: green;
}

label {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked id="c1" />
  <label for="c1"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: The Clip-path is not. I've deleted the other the suggestion as you were correct.